# What is the difference between the latent variable and the cluster weights in mixture models?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, latent-variable, finite-mixture-model

$p(x|\theta) = w_1 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^{2})\ + w_2 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2,\,\sigma_2^{2}) + w_3 \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_3,\,\sigma_3^{2})\,$

What is the difference between the the $w$ and the introduced latent variable $z$? I know that $z$ tells us from which cluster our data point came from, but Isn't that the same thing that $w$ does?
From my understanding, we introduced a latent variable to our model because we want to calculate the $w$
$p(x|\theta)=\sum_{c=1}^{3}p(z=c|\theta)p(x|z=c,\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a correspondence between the two. Particularly, in your second equation, we have $p(z=c|\theta)=w_c$ and $p(x|z=c,\theta)=\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_c,\sigma_c^2)$, and $\theta$ represents all the required parameter set.